# Flex 4.7: How to embed background music and remove Panel title bar?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, audio, panel

How can i add in the sound to play throughout the whole application without clicking any button in the simplest way?

and how am i suppose to remove the gray title bar in s:panel so that it is not visible?

Thankyou

Comment: Those are two very different questions; you should [post them separately](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275908/more-than-one-question-per-post).

Comment: the problem solved dy. i put the background music by using swfloader in the flex builder.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should read the [Adobe Helpdocs](http://help.adobe.com/) first. The most basics about Flex are compiled there.

> How can i add in the sound to play throughout the whole application
>   without clicking any button in the simplest way?

[This link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d27.html) should provide the most basic sound example, which you can embedd in your main application mxml, for example in an creationComplete event.

> and how am i suppose to remove the gray title bar in s:panel so that
>   it is not visible?

You can create a custom [spark skin for this component](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSC8DB0C28-F7A6-48ff-9899-7957415A0A49.html), where you control the appearance.